# How can I avoid poor execution plan selection in MySQL with large tables when sorting on indexed columns?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have three InnoDB tables on MySQL 5.5:

```
user_company_assignment (1.7 million rows)
 - id (int)
 - company_id (int) FKEY (company.id)
 - user_id (int) FKEY (user.id)

company (200k rows)
 - id (int)
 - name (varchar(255)) - Indexed

user (2 million rows)
 - id (int)
 - name (varchar(255)) - Indexed
```

Joining all tables and sorting by one of the indexed varchar fields has a good execution plan and is quick (~10ms):

```
mysql> explain select user_company_assignment.id, company.name
  from user_company_assignment
  inner join company 
    on user_company_assignment.company_id = company.id
  inner join user
    on user_company_assignment.user_id = user.id
  order by company.name asc limit 5;
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys               | key         | key_len | ref                                      | rows | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | company     | index  | PRIMARY                     | company_name  | 767     | NULL                                     |    1 | Using index |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_company_assignment  | ref    | fk_company_id,fk_user_id | fk_company_id | 4       | company.id              |    4 |             |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user | eq_ref | PRIMARY                     | PRIMARY     | 4       | user_company_assignment.user_id |    1 | Using index |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------------------+------+-------------+
3 rows in set (0.09 sec)
```

But when I join with both tables and sort by each of their indexed names, it picks a very slow execution plan and the query takes more than a minute to complete:

```
mysql> explain select user_company_assignment.id, company.name
  from user_company_assignment
  inner join company 
    on user_company_assignment.company_id = company.id
  inner join user 
    on user_company_assignment.user_id = user.id
  order by company.name asc, user.name asc limit 5;
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type   | possible_keys               | key         | key_len | ref                                      | rows   | Extra                                        |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | company     | index  | PRIMARY                     | company_name  | 767     | NULL                                     | 180792 | Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user_company_assignment  | ref    | fk_company_id,fk_user_id | fk_company_id | 4       | company.id              |      4 |                                              |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | user | eq_ref | PRIMARY                     | PRIMARY     | 4       | user_company_assignment.user_id |      1 |                                              |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------+-------------+---------+------------------------------------------+--------+----------------------------------------------+
3 rows in set (0.11 sec)
```

Is there no way to get an execution plan that will use the indexes on both of these table columns?  I don't expect it to be as fast as when sorting only by one column, but I feel like it should be only a little slower.

Comment: The keys come from two separate tables.  MySQL has to do a filesort.  I don't think there is any way around it.

Comment: Why do you need to read all the rows? If you want performance then read fewer rows (as it stands. Mysql needs to read all the rows before doing the sort and reducing the number of records).  And if you have a fast query but get a bad plan changing the sorting put the query in a sub-select. And don't use silly sized columns as your primary key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do what you want in a roundabout way.

Unfortunately, there is no way in InnoDB to create a key which includes columns from separate tables.  So MySQL is going to have to select every matching row if you sort by columns in different tables and then use `ORDER BY ... LIMIT` to cut them off.  After doing so, it can then sort that big resultset on disk, and finally select off the top few you want.

The solution is to reduce the number of rows that MySQL has to operate on by restricting the matching resultset to something manageable.

Since you know that you are going to have at most 5 results total, you can select the top 5 company IDs:

```
SELECT company.id
  FROM company 
  ORDER BY company.name ASC
  LIMIT 5
```

then do your JOIN using only those, and finally sort by company and user name:

```
SELECT user_company_assignment.id, top_companies.name
  FROM user_company_assignment
  INNER JOIN (
    SELECT company.name, company.id
      FROM company 
      ORDER BY company.name ASC
      LIMIT 5
    ) top_companies
    ON user_company_assignment.id = top_companies.id
  INNER JOIN user
    ON user_company_assignment.user_id = user.id
  ORDER BY top_companies.name ASC, user.name ASC
  LIMIT 5
```

[Here's a SQL fiddle demonstrating the query running](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27b22/3).  I threw in a small amount of data to test.

This will *still* pull in a fair number of rows to be filesorted, since you will be joining all of the employees for the 5 companies, but it should cut run time for your query by a couple orders of magnitude.

Comment: What if the first 5 rows do not have linked records?

Comment: Then you have 5 companies with 0 employees, which seems like a bigger problem.

Comment: This is clever and I can make use of it in some places.  I was hoping for something a little more straightforward where it could make use of both indexes I have defined, but sadly it seems to not be possible.

Comment: @john: The only real alternative in InnoDB is to create a denormalized table that combines all of the fields you wish to sort by so that you can make a single index that includes all of them.  Obviously, this comes with all the normal problems of data duplication.